# How to check whether a group contains users in BASH

Tags: bash

I'm writing a basic management program and need to be able to check whether a group has any members assigned before deleting the group.

Currently I am only checking whether the group name exists already.

```
if [ $(getent group $foo) ]
    then
        runFunction
    else
        resetTerminal
        tput cup 0 0
        echo "Group '$foo' doesn't exist, going back to menu..."
        sleep 3
        manageUsersMenu
    fi
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I know that you can list the members of a group but I am unsure how I can use this to have a check that just says something like:

```
if [ group has members ]
    echo "Cannot delete group as it contains members"
else 
    deleteGroup
fi
```

Comment: I've seen stuff like this.  However, I'm unsure how a list of users can help me determine whether the group has members. Unless you can do a check for whether it comes back null? Not sure how that would work, myself.  Thanks for taking a look.